# Wordpress .htaccess www. not forcing

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm trying to force www. on all the pages of my site. 
I have wordpress install in a folder on my main site (/blog). In the /blog folder there is an .htaccess file with the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

In the main dir of the site. I have a .htaccess file that has the follow:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.sitename.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.sitename.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^blog/index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ /blog/index.php [L]
```

In wordpress is have the option set for www. The www. appears on every page except the when I go straight the the site.com/blog address

Comment: Does the _"WordPress address"_ and _"Site address"_ include the `www.` in the URL under `Settings -> General`?

Comment: Correct it does contain the www.

Comment: Try replacing `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.sitename.com [NC]` with `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sitename.com [NC]`

Comment: That did not seem to have any effect. It still removes the www. on the main blog page

Comment: I've noticed that is only happens when I go to site.com/blog if I go to site.com/blog/ it does not happen.

Comment: add a .htaccess to / instead of /blog

Comment: When you say "it only happens/it does not happen", which one works?

Comment: Do you have the access to Apache httpd.conf? How is www.sitename.com and sitename.com are being configured in there?

Answer (score 8):

Go Settings -> General:
WordPress Address (URL) 
Site Address (URL)

And set both of them to www.yoursite.com (instead of yoursite.com), wordpress automagically takes care for setting all the urls to www.yoursite.com and that's it.

If that isn't enough, you shouldn't edit the .htaccess file anyway, because anytime you save or reload your permalink settings, Wordpress will overwrite your .htaccesss (some plugins may do that as well).

If you do want to rewrite your URL, you should do it with [WP Rewrite (Codex)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite), or if you want a little more simple approach, there is a good plugin for that called [Redirection (Wordpress.org Plugin Directory)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/).

In Redirection plugin you can just set the options to *.mydomain.com/* to redirect to www.mydomain.com/* with a 301, and that will take care of your htaccess as long as you keep the plugin active.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Both the Wordpress Address and the Site Address are set to www.site.com. I'd prefer not to have to run a plugin. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Why wouldn't you run a plugin ? If you don't want to run a plugin, I'm afraid your only other option is trying to run WP Rewrite from template functions file (not sure if that will work, but you can try that). You can't rewrite with just .htaccess. It's up to you to choose how to proceed. 
 
As I said before, I'd suggest the plugin, it is the easiest, and proper way to do things. You can also write a tiny tiny snippet of your own plugin.

Either write your own plugin (or functions.php), or use one existing, you'll probably end up using WP Rewrite, "Redirection" just does the hard work for you.

Comment: I don't want to run the plugin because, I want to know where the issue lies. The problem is not that I need to add a redirect it is that one is happening and it should not. Like I said in the comments above, if I go to www.site.com/blog it is being redirected to site.com/blog/ but if I go to www.site.com/blog/ there is no redirection.

Comment: Ok, so what is the root and home URL for your blog, how have you set them, with or without the trailing slash ? And maybe drop in a link to your actual site, so I can see that in action.

Answer (score 7):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 3):

In the .htaccess of the WordPress installation (/blog/ in your case), you can add the following code ABOVE the line that reads `# BEGIN WordPress`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.domain\.com\/subdirectory\/$1" [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
## Redirect primary WordPress URL to WWW version
```

Obviously, replace "domain.com" with your actual domain name and "subdirectory" with the name of the subdirectory where WordPress is installed. (/blog/ in the OP's request).

Comment: I realize this question is a few years old, but I searched the net ALL day yesterday trying to figure out this exact problem. It was only with the help of my web host (HostDime) that we were able to figure it out. Originally, I thought it was the configuration of the .htaccess in the site's root, but... turns out this extra code is needed to solve this problem. There SHOULD be a plugin for this, but since you never know how long a plugin will be supported....

Comment: This! Spent about an hour trying different htaccess rewrite rules. If you have a wordpress site in a subdirectory and want to force www, this is the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have Option for you:

1. using wp-config.php add:

   define('WP_HOME','http://www.domainname.com');
   define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.domainname.com');
2. using wp-admin

Log into your wp-admin
Browse to ‘Settings’ -> ‘General’
Under ‘WordPress Address (URL)’ and ‘Site Address (URL)’ add www to the address as shown below