# WWW Rewrite Wordpress inside a folder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

In "example.com" there is an index.html which is the home page of my website. The other pages are located in one wp "example.com/wp".

On my root folder (mysite.com), there's a .htaccess to add the www in the URL.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

When I access example.com, everything is correct: www.example.com

However, when I access my wp, www disappears.

Ex: example.com/wp/something, not as I would like www.example.com/wp/something

Here's the .htaccess wp folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks

Comment: Your URL in your WordPress admin needs to be set to use `WWW` and you also need to place your `WWW` rule inside your `wp` folder `.htaccess` as it is overwriting the rule from your previous directory.

Comment: Yes, it was unnecessary mess in .htaccess, just put "www" in Settings -> General. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the Wordpress URL to use `www` - so you need to go to the Wordpress admin area:

```
http://www.example.com/wp/wp-admin
```

Then proceed to `Settings -> General`
and there are two fields:

- WordPress Address
- Site Address

Set both to use the www prefix: http://www.example.com/wp/

I've just found the same written down here:
[Wordpress .htaccess www. not forcing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913856/wordpress-htaccess-www-not-forcing)

Comment: IT WORKS! Thank you! It was unnecessary mess in .htaccess